# Xcode Build skipping custom cocoapod

Tags: swift, xcode, build, frameworks, cocoapods

Recently I created a custom framework. It allows you to easily add Google Admob ads to your SwiftUI app. However, after installing the pod ( `import SwiftUIMobileAds`) to a test app I get a "Module Not Found" error (specifically for my custom pod other pods worked fine). So, I looked at the build output and found that it builds every pod besides my custom one. I don't understand why this is happening.

Xcode even creates a build directory for the pod it just never builds it.

The podspec appears to be fine. Why is Xcode doing this? Its almost like its skipping the build phase for build target "SwiftUIMobileAds"

[image]

[image]

[GitHub with Pod Information](https://github.com/pnut39/SwiftUIMobileAds/)

Answer (score 0):

In your podspec, change the line:

```rb
spec.source_files  = "SwiftUIMobileAds/**/*.{h,m}"
```

to include swift files:

```rb
spec.source_files  = "SwiftUIMobileAds/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
```